# MSDeploy fails with authorization error when using filePath provider

Tags: iis, filepath, msdeploy, msdeployserviceagent

I am trying to deploy a web application using MSDeploy. In the first step the app is deployed to test server (using the package created during the build), then to production server (source and destination are `iisApp`) and the next step is production `web.config` file deployment to the production server.

Everything works fine but the `web.config` file deployment reports an error

```
Error Code: ERROR_USER_NOT_AUTHORIZED_FOR_DEPLOYMENTPROVIDER
More Information: Could not complete an operation with the specified
provider ("filePath") when connecting using the Web Management Service. 
This can occur if the server administrator has not authorized the user for 
this operation. filePath http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=178034

Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_USER_NOT_AUTHORIZED_FOR_DEPLOYMENTPROVIDER.
```

I am using the same machine for deployment, the same username and the same password. I can see the user has `filePath` deployment enabled (as well `dirPath`, `contentPath`, `iisApp` and `setAcl`) in the Management Service Delegation screen in IIS Manager on the machine used for deployment:

[image]

It also fails for `dirPath` and `contentPath`.

Can anybody help? Thanks

Update - log when MSDeploy executed with `-verbose` flag

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy" 
  -verb:sync -source:filePath="C:\MyProject\DeployConfig\web\web.config" 
  -dest:filePath="web/web.config",computerName="https://deployement:8172/MSDeploy.axd?site=my-site",userName="publish",password="password",authtype="Basic",includeAcls="False" 
  -allowUntrusted -verbose

Info: Using ID '7fcedfe4-c103-48f4-ab98-4fae743d5eb7' for connections to the remote server.
Verbose: Pre-authenticating to remote agent URL 'https://deployment:8172/MSDeploy.axd?site=my-site' as 'publish'.
Verbose: Performing synchronization pass #1.
Verbose: Pre-authenticating to remote agent URL 'https://deployment:8172/MSDeploy.axd?site=my-site' as 'publish'.
Verbose: No backup was executed.
Verbose: Received response from agent (HTTP status 'OK').
Info: Adding MSDeploy.filePath (MSDeploy.filePath).
Verbose: The dependency check 'DependencyCheckInUse' found no issues.
Verbose: The current synchronization pass is missing stream content for 1 objects.
Info: Using ID '8f582c09-614e-4344-87c9-64867e44fc4e' for connections to the remote server.
Verbose: Performing synchronization pass #2.
Verbose: Pre-authenticating to remote agent URL 'https://deployment:8172/MSDeploy.axd?site=my-site' as 'publish'.
Info: Adding MSDeploy.filePath (MSDeploy.filePath).
Verbose: Received response from agent (HTTP status 'OK').
Info: Adding child MSDeploy.filePath (C:\MyProject\DeployConfig\web\web.config).
```

Comment: Use the MSDeploy -verbose flag to get more error details.  Posting your MSDeploy calls may help determine the cause.

Comment: I don't see the error details in the log you added.  I assume it still throws the error at the top of your post?  I wonder if its failing because IIS has a lock on the file.  Can you try stopping the IIS site and deploying the web.config?

Comment: Yep, it still throws that error. Stoping the IIS did not help :(

Comment: Try opening the trace logs at %systemdrive%\inetpub\logs\wmsvc\tracinglogfiles\w3svc1 and see what rule is failing to authorize.   More at http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/configure-the-web-deployment-handler

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: nope, moved away from that :(